# Sharepoint API returns ItemCount but not a list of files or folders

Tags: sharepoint

I'm accessing a Sharepoint folder that contains two files and a subfolder.  I'm getting back a correct ItemCount but no list of items.  Using a made-up path of /sites/sitename/folder1/folder1, and hence the following URI:

```
https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')?$expand=Files,Folders
```

The result comes out looking like:

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')",
      "uri": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')",
      "type": "SP.Folder"
    },
    "Files": {
      "results": []
    },
    "ListItemAllFields": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/ListItemAllFields"
      }
    },
    "ParentFolder": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/ParentFolder"
      }
    },
    "Properties": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/Properties"
      }
    },
    "StorageMetrics": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/StorageMetrics"
      }
    },
    "Folders": {
      "results": []
    },
    "Exists": true,
    "IsWOPIEnabled": false,
    "ItemCount": 3,
    "Name": "folder2",
    "ProgID": null,
    "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2",
    "TimeCreated": "2023-06-23T12:20:23Z",
    "TimeLastModified": "2023-06-27T11:06:16Z",
    "UniqueId": "12345678-1234-4321-8765-001234567890",
    "WelcomePage": ""
  }
}
```

I can see an ItemCount of 3 there, which seems to reflect my two files and a folder (and that number changes if I add/remove things in the web interface) but why am I getting an empty list of 'Folders' and 'Files'?

Comment: Hello, I just test on my site and the result is correct: both Files.results and Folders.results  have values. Can you check your documents are check-outed, and not extracted?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I have simply 'dropped' the files in place and used the web interface to create the folder.  As an aside, if I try to expand the 'ListItemAllFields' object, I get "The object specified does not belong to a list."

Comment: So, can you check on a document by clicking on the 3-dots if version history shows a version 1.0 for the document? On the library settings, you can also check on the "Manage files which have no checked in version" page if documents are not checked.

Comment: Version history shows a dialog with the main 'space' title at the top, a cogwheel and the rest empty.  Clicking the cog fills the middle of the dialog with a plain grey background with 'Site Content' at the top.  I've uploaded an Excel sheet, which makes the ItemCount now '4' but still a blank list of Files.  The spreadsheet details will show a preview and clicking on it opens it.